# I'm trying to create a guessing game but it won't work

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a guessing game where you have to guess a number between 1 and 10, however if you enter 0 then it quits the program. I managed to get it to work (minus the quit part) so I tried adding the next step, the quit feature. I'd assume based off the order of the else if that first if you get the correct number then it says "you won the game", which is what happens, however if the answer is wrong it just quits. I'm trying to get it to only quit if the user types in 0 but it quits no matter what number you type in (as long as it's not the right one) I've spent hours and hours trying different things but nothing seems to work. Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int secretNumber;
    int guess;
    secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);           

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");

    guess = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (guess == secretNumber)

        System.out.println("You won the game");

    else if (guess == 0)

        System.exit(0);

    else

        System.out.println("Invalid guess!");
}
```

Comment: You need a loop around that code, a `while` loop where you check if `guess` is 0

Comment: `(int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1)` will only generate numbers from 1 to 9.

Comment: you can make it two ways, in your case best one - to  make a loop (for, while). What you have done here - is just a peace of procedural programming, your code run from top to bottom and your programm just ends when bottom reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int secretNumber;
    int guess;
    secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    boolean playAgain=true;
    System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
    do {
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       guess = keyboard.nextInt();

       if (guess == secretNumber) {
           System.out.println("You won the game");
           playAgain = false;
       }
       else if (guess == 0)
           System.exit(0);
       else {
           System.out.println("Invalid guess!");
           System.out.print("Try again,Guess a number between 1 and 10:");
       }
   }while(playAgain);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this function is not recursively running. So it runs only one time and quits. Change your code as follows and try it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    guessingGame();
}

public static void guessingGame() {

    int secretNumber;
    int guess;
    secretNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 9 + 1);           

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");

    guess = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (guess == secretNumber) {

        System.out.println("You won the game");
        guessingGame();
    }
    else if (guess == 0)

        System.exit(0);

    else {

        System.out.println("Invalid guess!");
        guessingGame();
    }
}
```